# Risks for upgrading to Windows 10 for machines joined to a domain

Tags: windows-10-upgrade, windows-xp-mode

On 13 October 2015 (patch Tuesday) Microsoft added the Windows 10 upgrade notification to PC's which are joined to our work domain. With all the upgrade glitches and issue, is it safe to upgrade?

What happens to XP Mode, and the virtual machine(s) itself during the the upgrade? Our company depends on XP Mode for some legacy design software.

Comment: XP Mode isn't on Windows 10, and I'm assuming the VMs will cease to work upon upgrading but I'm not 100%. I assume also you'll decide not to upgrade so here's how to turn it off using Group Policy: 
Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Windows Update > “Turn off the upgrade to the latest version of Windows through Windows Update”